# Web Design, UX & Conversion rate improvments for our website + Blog Font Size

Tags: website-design

since we are just before the top of our season, and we are planning also to make a new website next year, we are collecting ideas on how to improve the current website.

For our home page [https://www.ncp-charter.com/](https://www.ncp-charter.com) we are curious to understand especially what elements do you think are missing on it. We know that not all things are aligned properly and that the website is not loading fast enough (currently we are also limited by the system the website is built in).

The same question goes for our landing page template, like [this one](https://www.ncp-charter.com/motor-yacht-charters.html). For sure we will add Client testimonials and our USP in some way on the landing page, like it is on the homepage, but would like to understand, what other things do you think, would these landings benefit from.

And as the last thing, since we are concentrating a lot of effort on our content, how can we still improve our [blog post page](https://www.ncp-charter.com/news/Croatia-yacht-charter-with-skipper.html). They are all made in the same way. We are also curious to understand if, in your opinion, the paragraph font size for blog posts is big enough, or if you would prefer it bigger.

As you can understand from the website content, we are a yacht charter company renting yachts in Croatia.

I would like to thank you very much already in advance for any helpful advice, info, ... We are searching especially for critical feedback, so do not be afraid to get off the chest, everything that comes to your mind.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This seems entirely too broad for this format. You're essentially asking for a full front-end webDev review. That's something you traditionally *hire* a company to do. Overall, It's a Bootstrap site, looks like most other Bootstrap sites. Not that there's anything really *wrong* with that. If you want more, you've got to push Bootstrap beyond defaults for things other than just colors/images. (Be aware, this does suspiciously look like spam - Posting images rather than links would make the question self-contained and avoid any implication of posting for SEO and link feeds.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically, I am looking for 2 things: **missing elements, that would benefit the website UX & conversion rate** for homepage and landing page. and for **an opinion about blog article font size**.

Comment: Regarding the spam implications, I would need to make and paste around 15 photos to share the whole homepage, landing page and important elements of the blog, and would not be able to present the natural font size on blog. I neither taught that links can be a problem, and from what I checked and see now, they are nofollow, so no SEO value from it. **Any way, if anyone has any good advice about the design, from the asked perspective, I will be really thankful**.

Comment: `:)` I didn't mean that it *was* spam... merely that it has common indicators of spam - low rep new user posting multiple links to one web site.  Customarily one would post [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCqtC.jpg) focusing on areas of concern. But again, I think this question, as it stands is *far too broad* and *any* answer would merely be opinion-based. Questions need to be answerable beyond *opinion*. It may help to [review the guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions) for critiques.

Comment: Re: the unintentional spam aspect. SE uses nofollow on new accounts so the links aren't contributing at all to any SEO measurements in any case, so it's not *actually* something we need to be worried about on that front. Agreed, though, it's way too broad to answer.

Comment: hey guys, I get it what you mean, and thanks for your feedback. Back to my post, would it make any difference if there were photos instead of links, or your point is more around the question itself, since you think is to broader?

Comment: I read also https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions so I basically get the picture. Anyway, if anyone needs my feedback for anything, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that your ultimate goal is improving conversion rate.

This is a **complex problem** that would require **lots of testing** on **real users**. I am not a real user, so I will only give you my first impression of the home page (Viewed on desktop).

**Conclusion: just hire a professional that specializes in conversion rate improvements**

---

### [Landing page](https://www.ncp-charter.com/)

**First impression:**

This page is simply overwhelming. It's difficult to find something to focus on. My only take away is that this is a "charter in Croatia since 1995". I'm not too sure what that means, and I can't seem to find an explanation easily or know where to go.

Deliberately scrolling down I see a place to book boats with models that I don't even understand the difference between. I see cabin, but cabin for hotel? On the boat? I guess From/To are length of time on the boat. But when do I go on board? What exact time?

So after playing around a bit, I think this is a boat booking site, but how does it all work? So the logos on the bottom mentions a bus shuttle service. Some 24/7 support. So maybe I should call you guys? Ok number is invalid.

**Analysis/suggestions:**

*You will need to conduct plenty of tests to verify if one technique is working well.

Please make it very clear what your website is about. Eg: "Enjoy the beautiful waters of Croatia! We offer yacht rentals, chartering, training so you can have the experience of your life. Book now." Looks like there's a lot more you your website, but I'm guessing this is what makes the most revenue (need a real world test to confirm). Make this part clearly visible, not a low contrast white on image.

Simplify the navbar. Contacts tab can reduce the number of rows (if web analytics shows low usage of phone and email section). Using the "NCP" part of logo would save space. Consider shortening the tab labels (again, must conduct tests to confirm effectiveness)

With the booking section be clear about the process and what is included (I needed a google definition of chartering and struggle to be convinced why I should use your service since I don't understand your process properly)

I have no comment for the other sections below, since I don't see how it's helpful to me. (may be helpful for others. Refer to your web analytics)

**Note: I am making a lot of assumptions about my experience that may not be best for most of your clients.**

Comment: **Thank you very much for your input**  Basically you already gave us a lot to think about and work on!

Comment: If you need any feedback anytime just let me know.